# redis in kubernetes: ReplyError: ERR invalid DB index

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, redis, microservices

When I try to connect to Redis service I get an error as :

```
 ReplyError: ERR invalid DB index
     at parseError (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:179:12)
     at parseType (/app/node_modules/redis-parser/lib/parser.js:302:14) {
   command: { name: 'select', args: [ 'NaN' ] }
 }
```

My Redis.yaml file like that:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:6.0.12
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: redis
  ports:
    - name: redis
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

And my Redis connection like that:

```
const redis_url = "redis://redis-srv:6379";

let myStatsQueue = new Queue('statistics', redis_url);

myStatsQueue.on('global:completed', (jobId, result) => {
    //...
});
```

Why I getting this error? How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're sure that your host is correct, try adding db number to URL so it will be: `const redis_url = "redis://redis-srv:6379/0";` (0 is default db for redis), maybe this lib doesn't fallback to default db